# malloc: *** mach_vm_map(size=18446744071761305600) failed (error code=3)

Tags: memory-management

I have a program that fails with this error:

```
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
ctffind(61810,0x7fff7a904310) malloc: *** mach_vm_map(size=18446744071761305600) failed (error code=3)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Operating system error: Cannot allocate memory
Memory allocation failed in xmallocarray
```

I have started to investigate with Xcode's Instruments and recorded the Allocations and Memory Leaks during the runs, and it seems to be that libfltk.1.3.dylib and CoreGraphics are using the most memory. But I have no idea what to do about it from here. I am not a programmer at all, I am just trying use a program I need for scientific applications. Is there maybe a way to recompile the programs so that there is a limit to how much memory it asks to allocate?

[Screenshot of Xcode Instruments Allocations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEgBi.jpg)

[Screenshot of Xcode Instruments Leaks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u32nd.png)

Parts of configure containing "malloc"

```
   { $as_echo "$as_me:$LINENO: checking for fftwf_malloc in -lmkl_rt" >&5
    $as_echo_n "checking for fftwf_malloc in -lmkl_rt... " >&6; }
    if test "${ac_cv_lib_mkl_rt_fftwf_malloc+set}" = set; then
      $as_echo_n "(cached) " >&6

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
#endif
char fftwf_malloc ();
int
main ()
{
return fftwf_malloc ();
  ;
  return 0;

 $as_echo "$as_me:$LINENO: \$? = $ac_status" >&5
  (exit $ac_status); } && {
     test -z "$ac_c_werror_flag" ||
     test ! -s conftest.err
       } && test -s conftest$ac_exeext && {
     test "$cross_compiling" = yes ||
     $as_test_x conftest$ac_exeext
       }; then
  ac_cv_lib_mkl_rt_fftwf_malloc=yes
else
  $as_echo "$as_me: failed program was:" >&5
sed 's/^/| /' conftest.$ac_ext >&5

    ac_cv_lib_mkl_rt_fftwf_malloc=no

{ $as_echo "$as_me:$LINENO: result: $ac_cv_lib_mkl_rt_fftwf_malloc" >&5
$as_echo "$ac_cv_lib_mkl_rt_fftwf_malloc" >&6; }
if test "x$ac_cv_lib_mkl_rt_fftwf_malloc" = x""yes; then
  HAVE_MKL="yes"
else
  HAVE_MKL="no"

{ $as_echo "$as_me:$LINENO: checking for library containing fftwf_malloc" >&5
$as_echo_n "checking for library containing fftwf_malloc... " >&6; }
if test "${ac_cv_search_fftwf_malloc+set}" = set; then
  $as_echo_n "(cached) " >&6
else
  ac_func_search_save_LIBS=$LIBS

     $as_test_x conftest$ac_exeext
       }; then
  ac_cv_search_fftwf_malloc=$ac_res
else
  $as_echo "$as_me: failed program was:" >&5
sed 's/^/| /' conftest.$ac_ext >&5
```

Sorry if it is long, I have no idea what any of this means and I can delete or add in more relevant parts upon request

Comment: Maybe post with context about the program (apparently ctffind?). Eyeballing it, it looks like the amount of memory it's trying to allocate is garbage; `0x7fff...` is a little shy of the largest positive number you can put in a 64-bit signed integer. I'm not an expert with anything involved here (ctffind or even OS X), so I won't be able to give you a solution here.

Comment: Even with enough info for others to solve it, it may still be a bad fit for StackOverflow--as you note this is about successfully using a particular program, but SO is for q's about making programs.

Comment: I have already asked the maker of the program about this, they said it looks like a Mac OS X specific issue, and they don't have experience with Macs so they can't help me.

Comment: My post about the issue on program website: http://grigoriefflab.janelia.org/node/5180 Yes I would like to use the program eventually, but I am wondering if I actually need to remake (at least recompile) the program so that it functions on my system. What would I even look for to find out how it is allocating memory? Would it be in a compiling configuration file or in the source code file .f90 ? Using TextEditor search for "malloc" in the .f90, but in the configure file I found parts which mention malloc (see my edited original post). Does any of it look like it can be changed to help?